# Hartley oscillator and feedback fraction

Tags: voltage, analog, oscillator

Do we decrease the the feedback fraction and increase  the amplification fraction if we increase the value of L2? (similar to Colpitts oscillator where we by changing C2 capacitor)
[image]

Comment: Precisely, what do you mean by *amplification fraction*?

Comment: [This answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/517675/how-does-the-colpitts-oscillator-reach-a-loop-gain-of-1/517814#517814) does a tear-down of the maths for a Colpitts Oscillator and you should be able to do the same for the Hartley if you follow that answer. It delivers the gain equation you might be seeking.

Comment: ... Tank circuit gain magnitude is \$\frac{L2}{L1}\$ at the oscillation frequency for a Hartley. For a Colpitts it's \$\frac{C1}{C2}\$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if we increase the value of L2? (similar to Colpitts oscillator where we by changing C2 capacitor)

Almost -- but you want to *decrease* the value of L2.  If you swapped the capacitors and inductors, then you would, indeed, decrease the value of the corresponding capacitor -- but inductive impedance goes **up** with increasing inductance, while capacitive impedance goes **down** with increasing capacitance.

> Do we decrease the the feedback fraction and increase the amplification fraction if

It's more complicated than that.  For any semi-reasonable starting point you decrease the feedback.  But you don't necessarily increase the amplification -- you just increase the amplification *that is needed*.  Just willy-nilly cutting the value of L2 (or adjusting the ratio of L2/L1 while maintaining the same resonance frequency) will eventually leave you with a dead lump of circuit that rings a bit when lightning strikes nearby but never breaks into continuous oscillation.  Before that happens, you'll have an unreliable oscillator, or one with poor operating qualities.

Comment: Tim if I recall correctly the dominant part in the equation of amplification of the Collpits oscillator Xc of the capacitor connected directly to GND is dominant.

Comment: @TheForceAwakens you might want to clarify what your comment means. It doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: I am saying that the load impedance is equal to Xc^2/Re where Re is the parasitic resistance of the inductor and Xc is the capacitive reactance of the C2 capacitor which is connected to ground for a Collpits oscillator.